# .htaccess RewriteEngine Probleme

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like : `www.mysite.com/truck/user/?l=2&lang=en&online=450215437`
i want to rewrite like : `www.mysite.com/truck/?l=2&lang=en&online=450215437`
Mean i dont want user folder apear on url .

I have try this in .htaccess file but not work :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(user\/\?l=([0-9]*)&lang=(.*?)&online=([0-9]*))$ index.php?l=$1&lang=$2&online=$3 [L]
```

Please help me :s

Answer (score 1):

That rule is wrong since `RewriteRule` doesn't match QUERY_STRING. Use this rule instead:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(truck/)user/?$ $1 [L,NC]
```

`QUERY_STRING` will be carried over automatically.

Comment: Also, Amine Joahave can have a look at this : http://www.jaredstenquist.com/2008/08/08/using-htaccess-to-remove-redirect-a-folder-in-a-url/

Comment: What didn't work? Did you place this code in .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT? Do you have other code there (if yes then place the code in question)